# Importance sampling estimate

Tags: statistics, numerical-optimization

Suppose that one is interested in estimating the tail probability 
 $$ P(Z \ge b) $$
for $$Z \sim N(0,1)$$ and a large threshold b. 
What is the expression for the importance sampling estimate with the alternative sampling distribution $$ N(\theta, 1) . $$ 
My answer: $$ P(Z \ge b) = E_f[h(X)] $$ 
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} e^{-0.5x^2} $$ 
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2\pi)} e^{-0.5(x-b)^2} $$ 
$$\frac{f}{g} = e^{0.5b^2 - bx} $$ 
important sampling estimate = $$\mu = E_g[h(Y)e^{-0.5(y-b)^2}]$$ 
$$\mu = E_g[1_{Y >= b}e^{-0.5(y-b)^2}]$$
Is this correct ?

Comment: @Djamel's comment: *this reference may be is helpful, 

    Hesterberg T . Estimates and confidence intervals for importance sampling sensitivity analysis. Math Comput Model 1996;23:79–85.*

Answer (score 1):

this reference may be is helpful,

```
Hesterberg T . Estimates and confidence intervals for importance sampling sensitivity analysis. Math Comput Model 1996;23:79–85.
```